# Redux + React + Typescript: How can I reduce the amount of scaffolding required?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm wondering if there's a way I can get around the need for instrumenting my Redux-Aware components.   It seems like an excessive level of scaffolding is required.

For example, here is the minimum code needed to declare a redux-aware component:

```
class _MyActualComponent extends React.Component<reduxScafolding.Action & { myReduxState: reduxScafolding.ReduxState; pushPath: ReduxSimpleRouter.pushPath; } & { myActualProp: string; }, {}>{
//my component's implementation goes here.
}

/** type for casting (so consumers know the props they are required to pass */
class IMyComponentVisibleType extends React.Component<{ myActualProp: string; }, {}> { };

/** instrument my component with redux */
export var MyComponent = ReactRedux.connect(
(reduxStoreState) => { //subscripbe to reduxStore updates (Called every change). 
    return { myReduxState: reduxStoreState.myReduxState }; //map myReduxState to props
}
, _.merge({}, {}, { pushPath: ReduxSimpleRouter.pushPath }, reduxScafolding.action) as any  //redux-binds, then includes the pushPath() method for use in our _App Component
)(_MyActualComponent) as any as typeof IMyComponentVisibleType;
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like an excessive level of scaffolding is required

The key things that *need* to be there repetitively:

- Some way to say what change a particular action brings to the store (+ code to dispatch such an action < this can be combined with the change definition ... see below).
- Some way to say what data from the store a component needs.

There is no killing these (fundamental) concepts so you will have at least 1 line for these two things. The rest can be abstracted away and that is what I do in http://alm.tools/ usage of redux.

Docs : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/docs/contributing/REDUX.md

Example:

## New Action

```
export let addTabs = redux.add('addTabs', (state:StoreState, tabs: TabInstance[]): StoreState => {
    tabs = state.tabs.concat(tabs);
    return {
        tabs
    };
});
```

## Connect to store

```
@connect((state: StoreState): Props => {
    return {
        errorsExpanded: state.errorsExpanded,
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Redux because of the overhead that's involved.  You can handle all of the CRUD operations on a form with just React fairly easily and save yourself the overhead and hassle.  Check this out...

http://bssdev.biz/HowTo/How-to-implement-full-CRUD-forms-with-React-and-asp.net-core